# Why did the Old English word "līċ" get displaced by "corpse"?

Tags: etymology, old-english

While checking the etymology of the English word **corpse**, [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corpse) says it had been **[līċ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lic#Old_English)** in Old English. [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lic#Old_English) also gives **/liːt͡ʃ/** as its pronunciation, which apparently is completely different from "corpse".

Wikitionary says

> From earlier corse, from Old French cors, from Latin corpus (“body”). Displaced native Old English līċ

I can't seem to find anything else about this word on Google. [Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/corpse) also seems to be of no help.

Why did "corpse" displace **līċ**?

Comment: Probably the French term was used in courts and medical contexts and finally replaced  the more “vulgar” OE term.

Comment: *Līċ* still survives in *lych-gate,* now probably its only use, and apart from some gamers I doubt that people actually know that *lych* means "corpse". Many French terms came over with the Norman Conquest and filtered down from court to peasant.

Comment: Lich meaning corpse still survives in southern England dialects: https://www.etymonline.com/word/lich

Comment: @AndrewLeach perhaps "... doubt that *many* people ..."?

Comment: Answers to 'why' questions in word history are hard to confirm - they all sound like idle speculation and really can't be confirmed or falsified. There's no one with a motive that makes a choice to one over the other, you can only attempt an answer of 'what happened' or 'is this the case'.

Comment: It's actively used in fantasy literature and narration. See [WP: lich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lich).

Comment: @Andrew Leach: That's simply not so.  Lich/lych is a reasonably common word, though the meaning has shifted from being an ordinary dead body (= corpse), to one that is somehow re-animated.

Comment: Can the close voters please explain how this is "opinion-based" and "needs details and clarity"? I would be so much obliged. As far as I'm concerned, I fulfilled the site's requirements and my question conforms to them. I did my research and found nothing that was easily available on the internet. There are hundreds of questions on this site that don't even show a single sign of research but no one is going to close any of them. Please explain.

Comment: Though not directly topical, are there presen-day languages which continue to have a cognate of this word, or a word of the same origin as lich?

Comment: German [Leiche](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Leiche), corpse, and various words derived

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### What Happened?

*Lich* in Old and Middle English referred to bodies in general. In the OED's two definitions for *lich*, that body could be alive (["lich, n.,"](https://oed.com/view/Entry/107962) def. 1) or dead (["lich, n.,"](https://oed.com/view/Entry/107962) def. 2). That's important to understand because *corpse* could also refer to a living or dead body ("[corpse, n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/41860)," def. 1 and 2).

Between Middle English and Early Modern English, two changes occurred:

1. *Lich* dropped out of usage, except in specialized combinations like the *lich-gate* or the *lich-house*.
2. *Corpse* increasingly pertained to a dead body, rather than to either a living or dead body.

### When Did *Lich* Decline?

*Corpse* (in earlier forms like *cors*) was in Middle English by the 13th century, according to the [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED9854), and stays in the language from then on:

> c1275 *Ken.Serm.*(LdMisc 471)216/55 : Mirre..defendet þet **Cors** þet is mide i smered þet no werm nel comme i hende.

*Lich*, in contrast, is swiftly disappearing by the 16th century, appearing primarily in printed editions of older manuscripts, like this (printed 1600 from a text dated to around 1350):

> c1600(c1350) Alex.Maced.(Grv 60)195 : With likand legges lovely too seene..Lili-white was hur **liche**.

The usage may have stuck around in spoken language for much longer, but usages in print after this point are intentionally archaic, like this 19th century ballad:

> 1806   Sir Oluf in Jamieson Ballads I. 222   Three **likes** were ta'en frae the castle away.

### Why does this replacement occur?

One guess is that speakers favored the more clinical, educated sound of the French-derived *cors*/*corpse* over the common use of *lich*. Such lexical substitution was common in the Middle English period due to the influence of England's Norman aristocracy ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influence_of_French_on_English)).

Another is that *lich* had an uphill battle because it looked the same as a very common word, *like*. The lists of forms for *lich* and *like* look rather alike; both could appear as *lic*, *lich(e)*, *lych(e)*, *lyke*, and *like*. They may have sounded the same too. So it's also possible that *lich* underwent a decline in usage compared to a similar-meaning word (*corpse*) in order to avoid confusion. At around the same time, *corpse* specialized to fill its current semantic niche.

Comment: As always, don’t forget to corpse and subscribe.

Comment: @Jim: [I'm sitting here trying not to laugh.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Corpsing)

Comment: Corroborating that last paragraph is the fact that the Dutch word for 'corpse' is still 'lijk', pronounced just like, well, 'like'.

Comment: Is there something to the fact that "lich" is like "like"? You also have "homo" as in "same/like" and "homo" as in "human" (though googling has failed to confirm that this is anything more than a coincidence either).

Comment: Duch also retains the form _lichaam_ `body' for the living body, google it.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins indeed, a common origin of the word(s) is usually assumed (en.wiktionary.org). This could be understood e. g. in *man-like*, which should have gone on to become *manly* (already before Old English), as in German *männlich*. But the origin is not quite clear. Kroonen lists Balto-Slavic comparisons for "similar, equal" and thus suggests "likenes, shape" to derive "(dead) body". Personally, I prefer an origin from reanalyzed suffixes (cp. Latin *-alis*, e.g., then as a sum of different morphemes) and a side of *lay, lie* for the corpse. "to like" seems exclusively English, AFAICT

Answer (score 6):

Certainly TaleisinMerlin's answer is weighty. Here's the addendum:

**Addendum**

While certainly lich has been dropped from the [vernacular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernacular), there is one particular language community in which its use is still strident, and that is the [fantasy genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy). My first encounter with lich(e) was as a child when I was introduced to it as a type of undead villan in one of [Gary Gygax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Gygax)'s modules in [D&D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons). In fact as noted by WP:

> In fantasy fiction, a lich (/ˈlɪtʃ/;[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernacular) from Old English līċ meaning "corpse") is a type of undead creature.

This is an excellent example of how a word whose [etymology](http://Etymology) shows that it hasn't been in use for hundreds of years, can be resurrected (yes) and regain currency pursuant to the whims of a language community. Of course, sometimes that leads to questions regarding a term's [phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonology). See this off-topic ELU SE post: [How to pronounce Lich](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449446/how-to-pronounce-lich). In this case, 'lich' is a [revenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenant) in both the literal and metaphorical sense!

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thanks for the encouragement! Your profile pic says it all. :D

Comment: Indeed. This [has come up before](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/449451/18696).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Of all the possible people to chip in, you *had* to bring your surname into this, no?

Comment: @Bakabaka It's pronounced differently, and is connected to tanning leather, not morticiary :-)